# Android Studio "Recommendations" for Virtual Device Configuration

Tags: android, android-studio, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I'm trying to create a new Android Virtual Device matching my own smartphone. For the system image I chose Jelly Bean (Android 4.3 (with Google APIs) from the "Other Images" tab. After completing all of my other settings, I'm prevented from finishing the config process by this "Recommendation":

[image]

Since it's a "Recommendation" which sounds like my settings could work anyway, how can I finish the process? Or am I forced to choose a system image from the x86 Images, or Recommended images?

Comment: It would take less time to just try it out, than to take a screenshot, post the question and wait for a response. And yes, it'll work.

Comment: The Recommendation is pretty clear, if you want to have better performance use an x86 images. Your selection is an arm image which will run slow on an x86 computer.

Comment: Previously when I tried an x86 image it "recommended" that I choose an image with Google API support. Hence I didn't have a way out and was trying to see if "recommendations" could be circumvented. I compromised by getting an x86 image with Google API support, but this doesn't match what I have on my phone. Does Android Studio really want to prevent virtual devices being made with "non-ideal" API's, even though they can work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing will happend installing a x86 system image. It will look as your phone if you set the same android version(Jelly Bean in this case)

More information in this:[Link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/03/06/now-available-android-sdk-x86-system-image-with-google-apis)

> To get the x86 system image with Google APIs, open up the Android SDK
>   Manager window in Eclipse, Go to the "Android 4.4.2/API 19" section,
>   and install both "Intel x86 Atom System Image" and "Google APIs (x86
>   System Image)", like so:

[image]